# Фильтр данных из массива

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

Есть массив с данными.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при выборе второго селекта выпадало два значения массива, а не одно?

Посмотреть код в работе можно [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ar0ntw/).

```
    var myvar = [  
        {name:"data1",val1:[31,91,181],val2:3},  
        {name:"data2",val1:91,val2:1},  
        {name:"data3",val1:181,val2:2}  
    ];

    function showFilters(){
        var filter = [];
        filter.push(document.getElementById('val1')
            .options[document.getElementById('val1').selectedIndex].value);
        var filtered_data = [];
        var data_accepted = true;
        for(i=0; i < myvar.length; i++){
            data_accepted = true;
            for(j = 0; j < filter.length; j++) {
                if(filter[j]!=='' && filter[j]!=myvar[i][('val'+(j+1))]){
                    data_accepted = false;
                }                 
            }

            if(data_accepted){
               filtered_data.push(myvar[i]);
            }
        }
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.innerHTML = '';
        for(i=0; i<filtered_data.length; i++) {
            container.innerHTML+=filtered_data[i].name+'<br />';
        }
    };

    function rbvalue(html_name){
        var undefined,default_value,i,rb_collection = document.getElementsByName(html_name);
        if(rb_collection !== undefined) {
            default_value = rb_collection[0].value;
        }
        for(i=0; i<rb_collection.length; i++){
            if(rb_collection[i].checked){
                return rb_collection[i].value;
            }
        }
        return default_value;
    }

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".filtering");
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
        elems[i].addEventListener("change", showFilters, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, проблема в том, что часть данных представлена в виде чисел, а часть в виде массивов. Тогда решением вашей проблемы будет все числовые данные приводить к виду массивов и искать только по массивам. Как-то так:

```
var data = myvar[i][('val'+(j+1))];
data = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];
if (... && data.indexOf(filter[j]) === -1) {
    data_accepted = false;
}
```

Тут стоит быть осторожным - насколько я понял, данные в массиве `filter` - строки, а данные в массивах - числа. `indexOf` ищет по точному совпадению  значения и типа, поэтому стоит привести значения фильтров к числовому типу.

Comment: если правильно понял вашу мысль...то боюсь вы не совсем правы, даже если оставть такой массив, то второй селект перестаёт показывать имя
var myvar = [  
    {name:"data1",val1:100500},  
    {name:"data2",val1:[800,100500]},  
    {name:"data3",val1:777}  
];

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, ещё раз напоминаю о необходимлсти приводить критерии поиска (элементы массива `filter`) к числовому типу (или данные - к строковому). С этим поиск работает. Сравните ваше решение и моё: http://jsfiddle.net/e5ar0ntw/1/